# Does Nvidia CUDA Toolkit run on Elementary OS?

Tags: graphic-drivers, nvidia

Is it possible to run Nvidia CUDA Toolkit on Elementary OS? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, it should work fine.

For actual instructions for the toolkit, go here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html